# Stream audio on Windows Phone 8 using MediaElement

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, audio-streaming

I'm trying to stream audio from an online source to a Windows Phone 8 app using MediaElement.

I have the MediaElement in the visual tree and it works with local files but when I try to use  files via a URL nothing plays and I get a MediaFailed exception. The media failed error has the code 3100. It neither worked with AAC or MP3 but worked with video.

My code:

```
sound.Source = new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
      sound.MediaFailed += sound_MediaFailed;
      sound.AutoPlay = true;
```

Maybe it isn't possible to do it this way, but if anyone could help it'd be appreciated.

UPDATE:

The file I've tried to use is http://rapidshare.com/files/2276097672/firework.aac. This file works locally on the phone but not online. Maybe I've misunderstood and I can't stream directly from this web location.

Comment: Can you share the source of the files so we can recreate? Have you confirmed the files are in a supported codec? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462087(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks Matt, I've updated the question. AAC is indeed a supported format.

Comment: The file is inaccessible - maybe that's the problem?

Comment: That is a very good reason why. Stupid mistake, must work different if you're not logged in. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file was inaccessible. Not really an answer as it's a stupid mistake but the problem has been solved.

Comment: @AshishJain I am indeed, you can see how I'm doing it in the Foundbite app.

Comment: i seen and nice work you did, but you are not showing the progress, and in my case to show the audio progress....

Comment: @AshishJain I am in the feed and on the full screen (there's a small green progress indicator).